# Why is this excel formula giving me a #name error?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is my excel formula:

```
=IF(ISNA,"0",(VLOOKUP(A2,Account_TS!A1:D312,4,FALSE)))
```

Note: I looked up the issue and it suggests that I have a keyword wrong, but I don't see what that might be.

Comment: =IF((ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,Account_TS!A1:D312,4,FALSE),"0".... Works.

Comment: Unless there's a specific need to return a text-formatted zero it's normally better without quotes around zero, i.e. use 0 rather than "0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you were trying to say the following:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,Account_TS!A1:D312,4,FALSE)),"0",(VLOOKUP(A2,Account_TS!A1:D312,4,FALSE)))
```

And, if you're using Excel 2007 onwards, you can wirte it as follows:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Account_TS!A1:D312,4,FALSE),"0")
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

`ISNA` is actually a function, so you need to pass it a value in order for it to work.

```
=IF(ISNA(A1), "Error", "No Error")
```

Comment: @DrewRush Haha, I know the feeling.